# Buscar palabras completas en una cadena que pueden o no estar rodeadas de "_"

Tags: python, python-2.7, regex

Estoy pasando dos listas por una clase `DictionaryMaker()`. Esto me va a generar un match entre palabras del ítem de una lista con el ítem de la otra, para así poder declarar cada ítem como clave y valor.

La clase y el método me funciona, pero para hacerlo más preciso he querido usar RegEx y el **`re.compile`** para afinar más los match.

- Aún no entiendo muy bien como va la sintaxis, me he leído muchas cosas y creo que el problema radica que estoy intentando algo como:

  ```
  (r'\b({})\b'.format(i))
  ```
- Esto me checkea la palabra por sus limites (*boundarys*), para que solo me detecte `'foo'` y no `'football'`. Lo que pasa es que en el otro ítem que está comprobando `'_foo_'` se encuentra entre barras bajas

  Sé que debo aplicar el `\w*` (CREO), pero no sé cómo.
- La cosa es que necesito que me haga un match incluso si esta palabra la encuentra entre barras bajas -- > `'foo'` match con `'_foo_'`.

¿Cómo lo podría lograr?

```py
import re

chekingList = [u'Hitch_neck_01_proxy', u'Hitch_head_proxy', u'Hitch_chest_proxy', 
           u'Hitch_spine_04_proxy',u'Hitch_spine_03_proxy', u'Hitch_spine_02_proxy',
           u'Hitch_upperarm_r_proxy', u'Hitch_lowerarm_r_proxy', u'Hitch_upperarm_l_proxy',
           u'Hitch_lowerarm_l_proxy', u'Hitch_hips_proxy', u'Hitch_upperleg_l_proxy',
           u'Hitch_lowerleg_l_proxy', u'Hitch_upperleg_r_proxy', u'Hitch_lowerleg_r_proxy',
           u'Hitch_foot_l_proxy', u'Hitch_toes_l_proxy', u'Hitch_foot_r_proxy', 
           u'Hitch_toes_r_proxy', u'Hitch_hand_l_proxy','nestor_colt_02_nes','maria_perez_04_vie',
           'juan_carlos_lara_curso','referendum_julio_jodido']

checkerList = [u'suck_neck_01_target', u'suck_head_target', u'suck_chest_target', 
           u'suck_spine_04_target',u'suck_spine_03_target', u'suck_spine_02_target',
           u'suck_upperarm_r_target', u'suck_lowerarm_r_target', u'suck_upperarm_l_target',
           u'suck_lowerarm_l_target', u'suck_hips_target', u'suck_upperleg_l_target',
           u'suck_lowerleg_l_target', u'suck_upperleg_r_target', u'suck_lowerleg_r_target',
           u'suck_foot_l_target', u'suck_toes_l_target', u'suck_foot_r_target', 
           u'suck_toes_r_target', u'suck_hand_l_target',]


class DictionaryMaker:

    # __INIT__
    def __init__(self,listA=None,listB=None):
        self.listA = listA
        self.listB = listB

    # Must Pass first the list what you want as KEYS 
    # Then pass the list that you want as VALUES
    # It Has FIXEDVALUE for TOLERANCE

    def Match(self,listA,listB,fixedValue=2):

        dictionary = {}
        for x,y in [(x,y) for x in listA for y in listB]:    
            def BreakWord(x):
                counter = 0
                list2Check = x.split("_")
                for i in list2Check:
                    find = re.compile(r'\b({})\b'.format(i))
                    if find.search(y):
                        print ("it Match")
                        counter += 1
                    else:
                        print ("NOT MATCH")    

                return counter

            counter = BreakWord(x)
            print counter
            if counter >= fixedValue:                
                dictionary[y] = x

        # print the dictionary Created for debugging
        for k,v in dictionary.items():
            print ("{} < -- is key from : ---- >> {}".format(k,v))
        print "            "
        return dictionary

dict = DictionaryMaker()
DicForTestResult = dict.Match(chekingList,checkerList)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Los `'_'` son parte de la palabra**

`\b` coincide con los [límites de palabras completas](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html). Es decir, en una **posición** donde a un lado tenga un caracter de palabra y al otro no haya un caracter de palabra.

Los **caracteres de palabra** (o `\w`) son `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. Como verás, el `_` también está incluido, y se considera como que es parte de la misma palabra.

Entonces, para solucionarlo, hay que modificar un poco la expresión para que coincida.

**Expresión regular**

Algunas opciones para que elijas:

1. Que coincida con `\bfoo\b` o `_foo_`

   ```py
   r'\bfoo\b|_foo_'
   ```

   - Esto también coincide con `'aaa_foo_zzz'`.
   - Demo: <kbd>[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/anC98a/1/)</kbd>
2. Lo mismo que recién, pero que `_foo_` no esté rodeado de un caracter de palabra.

   ```py
   r'\bfoo\b|\b_foo_\b'
   ```

   - Demo <kbd>[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/anC98a/2)</kbd>
3. Que coincida con `foo` si está alrededor de `\b` o `_`.

   ```py
   r'(?:\b|_)foo(?:\b|_)'
   ```

   - Esto coincidiría también con `'aaa_foo_zzz'`, o con `'foo_'`, o con `'aaa_foo.'`.
   - Usaría **esta expresión** viendo tus ejemplos.
   - Demo: <kbd>[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/anC98a/3)</kbd>
4. Que coincida con `foo` o `_foo_` completos, como en el segundo caso, pero escrito todo en uno.

   ```py
   r'\b(_?)foo\1\b'
   ```

   - Demo: <kbd>[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/anC98a/4)</kbd>

---

**Descripción de las construcciones utilizadas**

Para las opciones de arriba, se usó:

- `|` - Que funciona como [alternancia](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html). Es lo mismo que un **`OR`**, y tiene una de las más bajas precedencia en regex. Es decir que algo como `^aaaaa|bbb$` se interpreta como `^aaaaa` o `bbb$` (nótese que el `^` aplica sólo al primero, y el `$` sólo al segundo).

  La expresión `r'\bfoo\b|_foo_'` podemos pensarla como la unión de 2 expresiones alternativas.
- `(?:`...`)` - Es un [grupo](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). Sirve para eso, agrupar una construcción.

  En el caso de `r'(?:\b|_)foo(?:\b|_)'` lo estamos utilizando para que el `|` sólo se aplique a esas 2 opciones (y no a todo el regex).

  Es decir, `(?:\b|_)` coincide con una posición límite de palabra, **o** con un `_`.
- `(`..`)` - También es un grupo, pero es un [grupo capturador](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). Guarda en memoria el texto con el que coincidió. De esa forma, podemos referenciarlo luego en la expresión.

  En el caso de `r'\b(_?)foo\1\b'` estamos haciendo que *opcionalmente* coincida con un `_` (el [`?`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit) lo hace opcional). O sea que coincide con `_` o con nada.

  Como es el primer (y único) grupo que usamos, al [referenciarlo](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) com `\1` estamos haciendo que coincida con eso mismo: un `_` si había, o nada si no lo tenía.

**Código**

Demo del código con `r'(?:\b|_)foo(?:\b|_)'`:
http://ideone.com/XdgDgf

Ahora bien, quizás te interese que no distinga **mayúsculas y minúsculas**. Se establece pasándole [`re.IGNORECASE`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.I) (o `re.I`).

```py
re.compile(r'(?:\b|_){}(?:\b|_)'.format(i), re.IGNORECASE)
```

Por otro lado, estás comparando cada palabra dentro de cada ítem. Por ejemplo, con `'Hitch_neck_01_proxy'` estás construyendo una expresión regular diferente para `'Hitch'`, otra para `'neck'`, para `'01'`, y para `'proxy'`. Eso lo podrías hacer más eficiente.

**Todo en una misma expresión regular**

```py
re.compile( r'(?:\b|_)(?:Hitch|neck|01|proxy)(?=\b|_)', re.I)
```

y llamamos a [`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall).

Al final, en vez de usar `(?:\b|_)`, ahora usamos `(?=\b|_)`, que es una [inspección positiva](http://regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) que no va a consumir un caracter. Así, si está seguido por `_`, el próximo ítem también puede coincidir.

```py
for x,y in [(x,y) for x in listA for y in listB]:
    def BreakWord(x):
        list2Check = x.split("_")

        pattern2Check = '(?:' + '|'.join(list2Check) + ')'
        regex = r'(?:\b|_){}(?=\b|_)'.format(pattern2Check)

        find = re.compile(regex, re.IGNORECASE)
        resultado = find.findall(y)

        if resultado:
            print (r"r'{}'  COINCIDE CON    '{}'".format(regex,y))
        else:
            print (r"r'{}'  NO COINCIDE '{}'".format(regex,y))

        return len(resultado)
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/koi0nR

Comment: oye mas claro no canta un gallo ! esto es lo que estaba necesitando una explicación clara, concisa al punto y pythonica ! de verdad que todo merece un 10! si la pagina a donde has enseñado los demos es tuya te mereces una Donación! eternamente agradecido

Comment: @NestorColmenares jaja, no, no es mía. Es la mejor que conozco para compartir acá. Hay otros recursos listados en [la descripción de la etiqueta regex](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info)... Me alegro que te haya sido útil la respuesta ;-)